# Shorthand syntax for components in series

Tags: circuit-analysis, series

When doing circuit analysis, you can represent the mathematical operation of two components in parallel with the symbol "||".  Is there a similar way to represent the mathematical operation of components in series?  I'm doing my Circuit analysis homework and we are beginning to use source transformations.  I don't want to write out a complete sentence for "This source is in series with this transistor" Every time I do a transformation, lol. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use '+', which works for the mathematics of the resistances and impedances as well.

I also use it for the notation when I happen to be combining series capacitances, though of course they would not combine mathematically by adding. If one can't keep straight in ones head what's notation and what are equations, then it may be better to use a more complex symbol like \$\oplus\$.

Comment: But "+" doesn't work for capacitances (impedance aside).

Comment: That's right, it works for impedance, resistance and reactance, it doesn't work for susceptance, conductance or admittance. Is your notation glass half full, or half empty? If you're dealing with the ones it doesn't work for, how about something that looks like +, for the hint, but isn't + so as not to confuse you. '#' perhaps? Or maybe \$\oplus\$